# Get for specific tags the values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to build an sql query on an `oracle database`:

I am getting with two queries the following result sets.

*Result Set 1:*

Table **Tags**:

```
SELECT ProjID, Tag_Code, Value_numeric, Value_String from Tags;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ProjID             Tag_Code             Value_numeric     Value_String  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1             TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE             100              null       |
| 1             EXPOSURE_DATE                 null             1.1.2014   |
| 1             DEBT                          100              null       |
| 2             TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE             232              null       |
| 2             EXPOSURE_DATE                 null             12.05.2013 |
| 2             DEBT                          2324             null       |
| 3             TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE             3452             null       |
| 3             EXPOSURE_DATE                 null             19.03.2014 |
| 3             DEBT                          2345             null       |
| 4             TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE             3245674          null       |
| 4             EXPOSURE_DATE                 null             19.03.2014 |
| 4             DEBT                          12345            null       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

*Result Set 2:*

Table: **Project**

```
SELECT ProjID, CustomerName from Project;
+--------------------------------------+
| ProjID     CustomerName              |
+--------------------------------------+
| 1             a                      |
| 2             b                      |
| 3             c                      |
| 4             d                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

However, I would like to get this result set.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ProjID     CustomerName  TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE  EXPOSURE_DATE   DEBT         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1             a              100               1.1.2014      100         |
| 2             b              232               12.05.2013    2324        |
| 3             c              3452              19.03.2014    2345        |
| 4             d              3245674           19.03.2014    12345       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this possible in sql? How can I implement this? I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic way, compatible with your current table ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/523a1e/1/0)):

```
select
  p.ProjID ProjID,
  p.CustomerName CustomerName,
  (select Value_Numeric from tags
     where ProjID=p.ProjID
       and Tag_Code='TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE') TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE,
  (select Value_String from tags
     where ProjID=p.ProjID
       and Tag_Code='EXPOSURE_DATE') EXPOSURE_DATE,
  (select Value_Numeric from tags
     where ProjID=p.ProjID
       and Tag_Code='DEBT') DEBT
  from Project p;
```

Another way, in which `Tag_Code` values are stored in one `Value` column. With that, we can easily use `pivot` ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ade6/2/0)):

```
select
  p.ProjID ProjID,
  p.CustomerName CustomerName,
  TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE,
  EXPOSURE_DATE,
  DEBT from
  Project p left join
  (select * from
    (select ProjID, Tag_Code, Value from tags)
    pivot 
    (max(Value) for (Tag_Code) in (
       'TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE' as TOT_CUST_EXPOSURE,
       'EXPOSURE_DATE' as EXPOSURE_DATE,
       'DEBT' as DEBT
    ))
  ) t
  on p.ProjID=t.ProjID;
```

Using above `pivot` method will return `null` to the fields, if there's a record in `Project` table without corresponding records in `Tags` table.

Comment: Thx for your answer! What could I do if for one `Project`, lets say with `project id = 8`, there exists no entry in `tag`. How to handle that, without getting an error?

Comment: For the `pivot` answer: change `inner join` to `left join`, and then, the rest of the fields will be filled with `null` values. ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ade6/2/0)). **EDIT:** updated 2nd part of answer